# Prevent excel from closing when closing userform

Tags: vba, excel

I hope you can help me with this issue, I couldn't find any answer nor on google nor here. So here's the point:

I have to userforms. One of them opens on Worksheet_Open. In the Background I can still see the worksheet and the excel application. But when I click outside of the userform or close it, the application window disapears too. But in the open processes I can still see excel open.
My intention is to have the Excel window always open (in the background) so that when I close the UserForm the Excel Tables will be visible.
What do I have to code for that? To hide the userform didn't work for me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there if you want to use both excel and your Userform at the same time then go to your Userform property and make `ShowModal = False`